# How to delay cell protection when value is entered in a cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, data-protection

I have used following OnEdit() trigger code to lock cell after entering data first time:

```
 function LockCells(event){
 
  var range = event.range;

  var description = 'Protected';   // + stringDate;
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription(description);
  
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}

}
```

And when I enter a value in a cell as a user (not sheet admin), it instantaneously blocks the cell from re-entering value. Can we delay this process? I mean if we enter value now but the protection on that cell is applied after 10 minutes or one hour but not immediately?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `How to get protected range values using google apps script?` and `And when I enter a value in a cell as a user (not sheet admin), it instantaneously blocks the cell from re-entering value. Can we delay this process? I mean if we enter value now but the protection on that cell is applied after 10 minutes or one hour but not immediately?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your function of `LockCells` is executed by the OnEdit installable trigger.
- You want to run the script in the function `LockCells` after the OnEdit trigger is run.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script 1:

For example, when the OnEdit trigger is run, when you want to run the script in the function `LockCells` after about 6 minutes, the modified script can be a bit simple as follows.

```js
function LockCells(event) {
  Utilities.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000); // For example, after 5 minutes, the script is run.
  var range = event.range;
  var description = 'Protected';   // + stringDate;
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription(description);
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

When you want to run the script in the function `LockCells` after more than 6 minutes, the modified script is as follows. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please reinstall the OnEdit installable trigger to the function `LockCells`. By this, when you edit the cell, the edited cell is protected after 10 minutes in this sample script.

```js
var time = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes

function LockCells(event) {
  var date = new Date().getTime();
  var range = event.range;
  var a1Notation = `'${range.getSheet().getSheetName()}'!${range.getA1Notation()}`;
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var ranges = p.getProperty("ranges");
  ranges = ranges ? JSON.parse(ranges).concat({ date, a1Notation }) : [{ date, a1Notation }];
  p.setProperty("ranges", JSON.stringify(ranges));
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("lockCellsByTrigger").timeBased().after(time).create();
}

function lockCellsByTrigger(e) {
  ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers().forEach(t => {
    if (t.getUniqueId() == e.triggerUid) ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
  });
  var limit = time;
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var ranges = p.getProperty("ranges");
  if (!ranges) return;
  ranges = JSON.parse(ranges);
  var {rranges, r} = ranges.reduce((o, e) => {
    o[e.date + limit < now ? "rranges" : "r"].push(e);
    return o;
  }, {rranges: [], r: []});
  if (rranges.length == 0) return;
  p.setProperty("ranges", JSON.stringify(r));
  var description = 'Protected';
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  rranges.forEach(({a1Notation}) => {
    var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(a1Notation).protect().setDescription(description);
    protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  });
}
```

- When you want to change the time, please modify `time`. In the current stage, after 10 minutes, the edited cell is protected.
- The flow of this script is as follows.

  1. When a cell is edited, `LockCells` is run by the installable OnEdit trigger.
  2. Put the a1Notation of edited cell and the date to Properties Service, and install the time-driven trigger after 10 minutes.
  3. When the time-driven trigger runs the function `lockCellsByTrigger`, the edited cells after 10 minutes are protected.

#### References:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [newTrigger(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname)

Comment: Tanaike amazing. Modified script 2 works perfectly even if you edit multiple cells at the same time. It locked all the edited cells after 10 minutes. Thank you.